# max-height max-width 100% but stretching image while resizing browser

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
#containerDiv{
    width:40%;
    height:60%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
}

#myImage{
    position:relative;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}

<div id="containerDiv">
     <img id="myImage" src="img.jpg" />
</div>
```

When I'm resizing the browser it usually works well, but sometimes it will ignore max-height and stretch the image so that it fits the entire width of the parent div box. How do I fix it?

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot of the stretching?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code you posted. The image will never be larger than it's parent. Even if the image source is larger than the parent, it's going to scale down to fit inside. Do you have any other CSS rules for `div` or `img`?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of what you are trying to achieve, a very simple way to keep the image 100% of the parent div height with different screen widths, you can use absolute positioning.

```css
body{
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

#containerDiv{
    width:40%;
    height:60%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0px;
}

#myImage{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="containerDiv">
     <img id="myImage" src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/700/animals" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only scenario i can think is that you have somewhere in your CSS a rule that applies `width` or `height` by **X** value to your `<img />`

Here is a DEMO with the stretching:

https://jsfiddle.net/2pcrkL2v/2/

Comment: I don't have another rule that applies width or height, do you have idea other idea what it may be?

Comment: did you check inheritance?

Comment: You could avoid inheritance setting `width` & `height` to `auto` to your `#myImage` rule

Comment: ya i tried that before, but it didn't seem to work. There's no problem if i open the page in internet explorer. If i open the page in firefox it stretches horizontally only, if I open the page in chrome it stretches vertically only. So i don't know what's wrong with the code...

Comment: can you paste a fiddle? or a screenshot? is my demo working on your browsers?